# Why has 'last seen' been removed from display of user profiles?

Tags: discussion

When trying to assist someone, it is helpful to know the last time they visited your  dba.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com or other sites managed by your various offerings.
Thank you for the consideration of making this information available again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368298/why-are-last-seen-xxx-profile-views-member-for-and-visited-xxx-days-x), and the target of the dupe-closure for more detail about what has/is happening.